# Changing the background color of Tab Bar

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I am trying to get desired color rendered in the background of Tab Bar however I am facing problems. 
These are the things that I tried :-

1. Changing the background color of tab bar object from storyboard. The color rendered is always lighter than the desired color.
2. Programmatically  changing the color of the tab bar using the following code inside `viewDidLoad()` method

   ```
       self.tabBar.translucent = false
       self.tabBar.backgroundColor = UIColor(hexString: "323B61")
   ```

   It doesn't change the color. Instead , the color rendered is white.

How can I get the desired color for Tab Bar?

Comment: The only thing that worked right now for me was this https://stackoverflow.com/a/69260832/129202

Answer (score 94, accepted):

To change background colour of UITabBar

```
TabBarController* Tcontroller =(TabBarController*)self.window.rootViewController;
Tcontroller.tabBar.barTintColor=[UIColor yourcolour];
```

**Swift 3**

Based on the code above, you can get it by doing this

```
let Tcontroller = self.window.rootViewController as? UITabBarController
Tcontroller?.tabBar.barTintColor = UIColor.black // your color
```

or in more general

```
UITabBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.black // your color
```

Comment: also do: `tabBar.isTranslucent = false`

Answer (score 49):

We can also do it from `Storyboard`

1) Select the **Tab Bar** first:

[image]

2) Then from the Attribute Inspector choose **Bar Tint colour** as shown in the below image:

[image]

That's it!

Answer (score 32):

swift 4

Inside your UITabBarController

```
tabBar.barTintColor = .purple
tabBar.isTranslucent = false
```

You also have access to:

```
tabBar.tintColor = .green
tabBar.unselectedItemTintColor = .blue
```

to change icon colours if you want.

Answer (score 14):

try this code

```
self.tabBarController.tabBar.barTintColor =  [UIColor colorWithRed:0.376 green:0.729 blue:0.318 alpha:1.000];
```

Comment: Is barTintColor will work in iOS Devices below version 8.0 ??

Answer (score 12):

swift 5

```
self.tabBarController.tabBar.backgroundColor = .white
```

Comment: Thank you! So annoying that Apple keeps changing this!

Answer (score 8):

Swift 4, in viewDidLoad of TabBarController

```
    self.tabBar.tintColor = UIColor.white // tab bar icon tint color
    self.tabBar.isTranslucent = false
    UITabBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.blue // tab bar background color
```

Answer (score 2):

I leave this here...for anyone having this issue after latest updates.

```
if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
        let tabAppearance = UITabBarAppearance()

        tabAppearance.configureWithOpaqueBackground()
        tabAppearance.backgroundImage = UIImage()
        tabAppearance.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkBlueDF

        tabAppearance.stackedLayoutAppearance.selected.titleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
        tabAppearance.stackedLayoutAppearance.selected.iconColor = UIColor.white

        tabAppearance.stackedLayoutAppearance.normal.iconColor = UIColor.gray
        tabAppearance.stackedLayoutAppearance.normal.titleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: UIColor.gray]

        UITabBar.appearance().standardAppearance = tabAppearance

        if #available(iOS 15, *) {
            UITabBar.appearance().scrollEdgeAppearance = tabAppearance
        }

        setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()

        tabBarController?.tabBar.tintColor = .white
        tabBarController?.tabBar.barTintColor = UIColor.darkBlueDF
        tabBarController?.tabBar.isTranslucent = false
    } else {
        // Handle older versions prior to iOS 13.0
        tabBarController?.tabBar.tintColor = .white
        tabBarController?.tabBar.barTintColor = UIColor.darkBlueDF
        tabBarController?.tabBar.isTranslucent = false
    }
```