# iOS 15 UITabBarController's tabBar background color turns black

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar, ios15

`tabBar.barTintColor` can't be changed in iOS 15 beta 4.

**Background**. We have an app in App Store and each year before the new iOS major version releases we download the iOS beta and test our app to fix the issues beforehand.

**Our problem**. This year when testing in iOS 15 beta 4 we found the UITabBarController's tabBar background color turns black and makes the item (both icon and title) hard to read. In our code we had self.tabBar.barTintColor = .white and this line of code doesn't work in iOS 15.

**Our attempts**. I search online and found a similar, not exactly the same, issue reported, https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/682420. And I tried `standardAppearance` but this is not the solution since with `appearance` I can't change `tabBar.tintColor`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60038183/ios13-uitabbar-tintcolor-for-unselecteditem-not-working

Answer (score 94):

I had the same issue and found the same link that is in your question. I used the same approach for the tab bar.

This is the code i am using and it works perfectly.

```
if #available(iOS 15.0, *) {
   let appearance = UITabBarAppearance()
   appearance.configureWithOpaqueBackground()
   appearance.backgroundColor = customColor
   
   self.tabController.tabBar.standardAppearance = appearance
   self.tabController.tabBar.scrollEdgeAppearance = view.standardAppearance
}
```

Comment: Thanks for responding. Unfortunately in our app we also need to set tabBar.tintColor besides tabBar.barTintColor, but with appearance we don't have access to tabBar.tintColor. But glad to know we are not the only case and hope Apple will notice my report.

Comment: @ZhengqianKuang, did you find a solution to tabBar.tintColor issue? I also need to have it set.

Comment: @Jerry see answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69200041/2108547
Variable names correlate to what they're replacing.

Comment: `tabBar.scrollEdgeAppearance` is a new API on iOS 15 which must be set, setting the same appearance to that property "fixed" the issue

Comment: I had to use almost all the same lines, except for the appearance.configureWithOpaqueBackground() one. But it might depend I guess on your colors/translucency. Mine had a blue tintColor and white background. Now it works perfectly again, also with the 'prefersLargeTitles'!

Comment: tabBarController?.tabBar.scrollEdgeAppearance = tabBarController?.tabBar.standardAppearance

Comment: Should it be `self.tabBar.scrollEdgeAppearance = appearance`? View doesn't have standardAppearance property.

Comment: Also works for the status bar if you separately declare an instance of `UINavigationBarAppearance` and apply these same properties.

Answer (score 59):

Similar to an answer above but with a fix for view not being recognised if you are using custom classes:

```
if #available(iOS 15.0, *) {
    let appearance = UITabBarAppearance()
    appearance.configureWithOpaqueBackground()
    appearance.backgroundColor = .white
    tabBar.standardAppearance = appearance
    tabBar.scrollEdgeAppearance = tabBar.standardAppearance
}
```

Comment: It's better to use `.systemBackground` as `backgroundColor`, since that will automatically change to black in Dark Mode.

Comment: Thank you..Put this code into tabbarcontroller and it worked for me

Answer (score 23):

Create a `UITabBarAppearance` like this to maintain the same visual behavior as previous iOS versions:

```
@available(iOS 15.0, *)
private func updateTabBarAppearance() {
    let tabBarAppearance: UITabBarAppearance = UITabBarAppearance()
    tabBarAppearance.configureWithOpaqueBackground()
    
    let barTintColor: UIColor = .white
    tabBarAppearance.backgroundColor = barTintColor
    
    updateTabBarItemAppearance(appearance: tabBarAppearance.compactInlineLayoutAppearance)
    updateTabBarItemAppearance(appearance: tabBarAppearance.inlineLayoutAppearance)
    updateTabBarItemAppearance(appearance: tabBarAppearance.stackedLayoutAppearance)
    
    self.tabBar.standardAppearance = tabBarAppearance
    self.tabBar.scrollEdgeAppearance = tabBarAppearance
}

@available(iOS 13.0, *)
private func updateTabBarItemAppearance(appearance: UITabBarItemAppearance) {
    let tintColor: UIColor = .red
    let unselectedItemTintColor: UIColor = .green
    
    appearance.selected.iconColor = tintColor
    appearance.normal.iconColor = unselectedItemTintColor
}
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing.
Can please share the purpose of inlineLayoutAppearence. Because stackedLayoutAppearence fixes the issue. Couldnt understand the purpose of other two

Answer (score 23):

I tried above answers which are correct. I want to add more properties in those solutions. My requirement was to change **background color** of tab bar , changing **selected image and title color**, changing **un selected image and title color**. I was able to achieve it in **iOS 15** using below code.

```
if #available(iOS 15.0, *){
    let appearance = UITabBarAppearance()
    appearance.configureWithDefaultBackground()
    appearance.backgroundColor = UIColor.appDarkColorLightShade
    
    appearance.compactInlineLayoutAppearance.normal.iconColor = .lightText
    appearance.compactInlineLayoutAppearance.normal.titleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor : UIColor.lightText]
    
    appearance.inlineLayoutAppearance.normal.iconColor = .lightText
    appearance.inlineLayoutAppearance.normal.titleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor : UIColor.lightText]
    
    appearance.stackedLayoutAppearance.normal.iconColor = .lightText
    appearance.stackedLayoutAppearance.normal.titleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor : UIColor.lightText]
    
    self.tabBarController?.tabBar.standardAppearance = appearance
    self.tabBarController?.tabBar.scrollEdgeAppearance = self.tabBarController?.tabBar.standardAppearance
    self.tabBarController?.tabBar.tintColor = .white
    
}else{
    self.tabBarController?.tabBar.barTintColor = .appDarkColorLightShade
    self.tabBarController?.tabBar.unselectedItemTintColor = .lightText
    self.tabBarController?.tabBar.tintColor = .white
    
}
```

Answer (score 16):

**iOS 15**: We saw this. This is what I changed in our storyboard to make it work:
[image]

This slightly altered the appearance in iOS 14, but it was ok for our needs.

Answer (score 10):

For me it's simple and you don't need to get access to `UINavigationController` instance. Just call it from `AppDelegate:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`

```
if #available(iOS 15.0, *) {
    let appearance = UITabBarAppearance()
    appearance.configureWithOpaqueBackground()
    UITabBar.appearance().standardAppearance = appearance
    UITabBar.appearance().scrollEdgeAppearance = appearance
}
```

Answer (score 6):

My tab bar was transparent. And this:`tabBar.scrollEdgeAppearance = tabBar.standardAppearance` doesn't do the trick for me.

I had to replace it with `tabBar.scrollEdgeAppearance = appearance`. I assume it's the same for navigation bar too.

So the final fix looks like:

```
   if #available(iOS 15.0, *) {
        let appearance = UITabBarAppearance()
        appearance.configureWithOpaqueBackground()
        appearance.backgroundColor = .white //or whatever your color is
        
        tabBar.scrollEdgeAppearance = appearance
        tabBar.standardAppearance = appearance
    }
```

Also the *Rafat touqir Rafsun*'s answer above works fine if you want to set the appearance in the appdelegate.

Tested on iOS 15.0.1, Xcode 13.

Answer (score 5):

Here's my implementation, Objective-C, for both `UITabBar` and `UINavigationBar`. They're pretty much the same.

Call this in the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` in your `AppDelegate.m`.

```
- (void)setupAppearance {
  if (@available(iOS 15, *)) {
    UIColor *color = [UIColor whiteColor]; // #F5F5F5 for white smoke. 
    UITabBarAppearance *tabBarAppearance = [UITabBarAppearance new];
    tabBarAppearance.backgroundColor = color;
    [[UITabBar appearance] setStandardAppearance:tabBarAppearance];
    [[UITabBar appearance] setScrollEdgeAppearance:tabBarAppearance];
    
    UINavigationBarAppearance *navBarAppearance = [UINavigationBarAppearance new];
    navBarAppearance.backgroundColor = color;
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setStandardAppearance:navBarAppearance];
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setScrollEdgeAppearance:navBarAppearance];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

My app has an opaque tab bar below a table view. In iOS 14.x and earlier, it was sufficient to set the `barTintColor` on a `UIAppearance` proxy, but in iOS 15.0 the tab bar background was black when the table view didn't reach the bottom of the screen.

My solution for iOS 15 is to continue using the `UIAppearance` proxy rather than the newer `UITabBarAppearance` class. I just needed to set `backgroundColor` in addition to `barTintColor`. This is backward compatible at least to iOS 11.

```swift
let tabBarAppearance = UITabBar.appearance()
tabBarAppearance.isTranslucent = false
tabBarAppearance.barTintColor = barColor
tabBarAppearance.backgroundColor = barColor
```

Comment: Thanks! I had the same issue when the tableView didn't reach the bottom of the screen, and this helped.

Answer (score 3):

Xcode 13.0 - iOS 15.0

My goal was to update the navigation bar tint color dynamically on the view controller change. I set [these](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69054423/13116047) settings first. Then called this function when needed with UIColor I want to use.

Call:

```
setNavigationBarAppearance(color: .green)
```

Extension:

```
// MARK: Navigation Bar Appearance Function
extension MainViewController {
    func setNavigationBarAppearance(color: UIColor) {
        if #available(iOS 15.0, *){
            let appearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
            appearance.configureWithDefaultBackground()
            appearance.backgroundColor = color // The background color.
            
            self.navigationController?.navigationBar.standardAppearance = appearance
            self.navigationController?.navigationBar.scrollEdgeAppearance = self.navigationController?.navigationBar.standardAppearance
            
        } else { // Background color support for older versions
            self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = color
            
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT:
Navigation bar tint color won't work on earlier devices while using [these](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69054423/13116047) settings, sorry for the misinformation. Reverting the settings below makes the tint color works as intended in all versions.

My settings (Tint color works perfectly, on iOS 13.5 and iOS 15):

[image]

Answer (score 3):

For Swift, I use code below to keep my app has the same look as before. My tabbar has pink selected color for both icon & title. And with default gray tint color.

To use `configureWithDefaultBackground` instead of `configureWithOpaqueBackground` because I want a bit transparency of the tabbar.

For now, it is working well, keep looking for the latest changes.

```
       if #available(iOS 15, *) {
            let appearance = UITabBarAppearance()
            appearance.configureWithDefaultBackground()
            appearance.stackedLayoutAppearance.normal.iconColor = .systemGray
            appearance.stackedLayoutAppearance.normal.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.systemGray]
            
            appearance.stackedLayoutAppearance.selected.iconColor = .systemPink
            appearance.stackedLayoutAppearance.selected.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.systemPink]
            // appearance.backgroundColor = .systemBackground
            
            self.tabBar.standardAppearance = appearance
            self.tabBar.scrollEdgeAppearance = appearance
        }
        
        if #available(iOS 13, *) {
            let appearance = UITabBarAppearance()
            appearance.shadowImage = UIImage()
            appearance.shadowColor = .white
            
            appearance.stackedLayoutAppearance.normal.iconColor = .systemGray
            appearance.stackedLayoutAppearance.normal.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.systemGray]
//            appearance.stackedLayoutAppearance.normal.badgeBackgroundColor = .yellow
            
            appearance.stackedLayoutAppearance.selected.iconColor = .systemPink
            appearance.stackedLayoutAppearance.selected.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.systemPink]

            self.tabBar.standardAppearance = appearance
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
  if #available(iOS 15.0, *) {
    navigationController?.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.colorName
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

After update to XCode 13 & iOS 15 I also faced some Tab Bar issues with bar background color and items text color for different states. The way I fixed it:

```
if #available(iOS 15, *) {
   let tabBarAppearance = UITabBarAppearance()
   tabBarAppearance.backgroundColor = backgroundColor
   tabBarAppearance.stackedLayoutAppearance.selected.titleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: selectedItemTextColor]
   tabBarAppearance.stackedLayoutAppearance.normal.titleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: unselectedItemTextColor]
   tabBar.standardAppearance = tabBarAppearance
   tabBar.scrollEdgeAppearance = tabBarAppearance
} else {
   UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([.foregroundColor: selectedItemTextColor], for: .selected)
   UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([.foregroundColor: unselectedItemTextColor], for: .normal)
   tabBar.barTintColor = backgroundColor
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want settings up scrollEdgeAppearance, you can override it as standardAppearance, and all your settings will be in both appearance.

```
if #available(iOS 15.0, *) {
   tabBar.scrollEdgeAppearance = tabBar.standardAppearance
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
     func setupAppearance() {
            // Update based on your font requirements
            let font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12, weight: .bold)
            let tabBarAppearance = UITabBarAppearance()
            let tabBarItemAppearance = UITabBarItemAppearance()
            
            tabBarItemAppearance.normal.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.font: font, NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.gray]
            tabBarItemAppearance.selected.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.font: font, NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.black]

            /* Note: To reset background and shadow properties to display opaque colors can use - tabBarAppearance.configureWithOpaqueBackground() */
            tabBarAppearance.backgroundColor = .white
            tabBarAppearance.stackedLayoutAppearance = tabBarItemAppearance
            
            tabBar.standardAppearance = tabBarAppearance
        if #available(iOS 15.0, *) {
            tabBar.scrollEdgeAppearance = tabBarAppearance
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

this is perfect way to fix the tabbar items title color for select and normal items

```
let tabBarAppearance = UITabBarAppearance()
let tabBarItemAppearance = UITabBarItemAppearance()

tabBarItemAppearance.normal.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.red]
tabBarItemAppearance.selected.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.blue]

tabBarAppearance.stackedLayoutAppearance = tabBarItemAppearance

tabBar.standardAppearance = tabBarAppearance
tabBar.scrollEdgeAppearance = tabBarAppearance
```

Answer (score -1):

Inside subclass of UITabBarController

```
if #available(iOS 15.0, *) {
            let appearance = UITabBarAppearance()
            appearance.configureWithOpaqueBackground()
            appearance.backgroundColor = .white
            tabBar.standardAppearance =  appearance
            tabBar.scrollEdgeAppearance = tabBar.standardAppearance
        }
```

Comment: How is this any different from the existing https://stackoverflow.com/a/68749895/341994 ?