# UITabBarController BarTintColor not working in iOS15

Tags: xamarin.ios, ios15, bartintcolor

In iOS15, I came across an issue that the bottom bar's color not showing a correct color and it changed into transparent/white. The same code works good in iOS14 & iOS13.

I have a tab bar renderer class for iOS, in ViewWillAppear(), I use code `TabBar.BarTintColor = UIColor.Blue` to change tab bar color, it works only for iOS below than iOS15 but not in iOS15.

Based on this [issue](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/682420), I assuming I need to convert the code from UINavigationBar to UITabBar. However, I don't see any reference to "scrollEdgeAppearance" in UITabBar class. I believe this is important to fix the issue.  I'd be grateful if someone can give me some advice. Many Thanks.

**Code to change Tab bar color that works in iOS14 & iOS13**

```
TabBar.BarTintColor = UIColor.Blue;
```

**UINavigationBar**

```
    let appearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
    appearance.configureWithOpaqueBackground()
    appearance.backgroundColor = <your tint color>
    navigationBar.standardAppearance = appearance;
    navigationBar.scrollEdgeAppearance = navigationBar.standardAppearance
```

**my own UITabBar code**

```
     var appearance = new UITabBarAppearance();
     appearance.ConfigureWithOpaqueBackground();
     appearance.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Blue;
     this.TabBarController.TabBar.StandardAppearance = appearance;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Studio for Mac now includes Xamarin.iOS 15.0.0.6 updates.

I updated Visual Studio for Mac to Version 8.10.9 (build 3) and Xamarin.iOS to 15.0.0.6

I resolved the UITabBar bar color with following code:

```
var appearance = new UITabBarAppearance();
appearance.ConfigureWithOpaqueBackground();
appearance.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Blue; // color you want

TabBar.StandardAppearance   = appearance;
TabBar.ScrollEdgeAppearance = TabBar.StandardAppearance;
```

*** As on date of 30 Sept, you might still see no reference to "scrollEdgeAppearance" in UITabBar class if you're using Visual Studio for Windows. You can ignore it because you can still build the project without errors.

Comment: Did you manage light and dark theming (I mean dynamically) ?

Answer (score 1):

Have you ever checked this link:https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues/12778 ?

Since currently there is no update for iOS 15 in visual studio so we need to download the pkg file and install `Xamarin.iOS` manually to test iOS 15.

I download and install it , use the following code , everything works fine .

```
if(UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion(15,0))
{

   var appearance = new UITabBarAppearance();
   appearance.ConfigureWithOpaqueBackground();
   appearance.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Blue;

   tab.TabBar.StandardAppearance = appearance;
   tab.TabBar.ScrollEdgeAppearance = tab.TabBar.StandardAppearance;
}
```

[image]

Refer to

https://stackoverflow.com/a/68749895/8187800.

Comment: May I know which version of pkg file you downloaded? Do you mind also sharing your current version of Xamarin.IOS ?

Comment: Xamarin.iOS 15.0.0.6 , just download the pkg file in the link and click to install on your mac.

Answer (score 1):

Just fixed this issue but in Xamarin.Forms: The tabbar had a white/transparent color in iOS 15.

1. Update VS for Mac (8.10.10 build 8).
2. Install latest Xamarin.iOS (15.0.0.6).
3. Use UITabBar: Add the following code somewhere in FinishedLaunching in App_Delegate.cs:

```cs
UITabBar.Appearance.BackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("333333").ToUIColor();
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think you are looking for the current ViewController's navigation item:

Try something like

```
        var appearance = new UINavigationBarAppearance();
        appearance.ConfigureWithOpaqueBackground();
        appearance.BackgroundColor = *Your color*;
        tabBar.NavigationItem.StandardAppearance = appearance;
        tabBar.NavigationItem.ScrollEdgeAppearance = tabBar.NavigationItem.StandardAppearance;
```

Where tabBar is the UITabBarController Object

Goodluck

Comment: No luck. Tab bar still showing transparent/white color for iOS15

Comment: Can you add a picture of what part of the UI are you trying to change?

Comment: Can you try the above as well @WeiLoonWong

Comment: we change Tab Bar color by implementing TabBar.BarTintColor = UIColor.Blue; TabBar is coming from UITabBarController. I tried the code above but it still shows transparent/white color.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use classe inherit from UIBarAppearance.

I wrote an article talking UINavigationBar on iOS 15, but I also talking about other components like UITabBar. You can check here: https://medium.com/@eduardosanti/uinavigationbar-is-black-on-ios-15-44e7852ea6f7

Comment: I tried the same appearance setting for UITabBar, however, there is no reference to "scrollEdgeAppearance" in UITabBar class. I think "scrollEdgeAppearance" is necessary to resolve the issue. I'd no clue how to resolve the same problem for UITabBar without 'scrollEdgeAppearance' :(

Comment: Apple introduced the scrollEdgeAppearance in iOS 15 for TabBar too.

Something like UITabBar().scrollEdgeAppearance